# What does ExactTarget use for a file include?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

We have a set of details within our website which translates numerous elements based on a language selector. Currently atop each of several pages there is a variable for language accessed via RequestParameter. The language selected determines which of the if/then sets of translated terms will apply to the pages set variables such as "@MoreInfoBtn". This means each of the pages has about 100 lines of code. Since this code is identical on all 3 pages, it would make sense to simply include a link to a file which holds all of this code so we can update one file to affect numerous pages. Does ExactTarget's ampscript feature something like an "include" that will accomplish this?

```
IF @LangID == "11" THEN 
   SET @LangName = "English" 
   SET @LVarThankYouReg = "Thank you for registering" 
   SET @LVarWebLink = "WebLink" 
   SET @LVarWebPW = "Password" 
   SET @LVarFeaturedContent = "Featured Content" 
   SET @LVarRegNowBtn = "Register" 
   SET @LVarMoreInfoBtn = "Info" 
ENDIF
```

and repeated for multiple other languages.

Comment: What kind of code are you including? Is it just a group of AMP script variables?

Comment: A set of if/thens for various languages which will then reset text for multiple variables that may appear on the pages. I'm adding that code to the question above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't load static files - use the built in Content Areas provided by ExactTarget - they will be quicker.  More info on creating those [here](http://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/content/email_overview/content_boxes/content_building_wizard/).

Simplifying answer based on feedback - Use one content area as your logic layer.

In your file - simply use `ContentAreaByName()` and pull in the language logic.  Your page will have already read the query parameter and the content area will also be aware of it.

Your logic layer will, based on the query parameter, select and perform `ContentAreaByName()` to grab the specific localized AMPscript variables.

I wouldn't recommend loading them in one single group, as it would eventually become a load on the server, and not something you want to try to undo later on.

Comment: Normally I agree that the browsers language preference would be priority but in this circumstance the priority is actually the language of an event/publication. So if the event is set to be in Spanish, then the "register" button should also be in Spanish. Even if the browser is in the US and in English. The page works as is but this set of translations is adding 150 lines of code already to all related pages in order to set the value of half a dozen variables. If I could link to one file (a la "include") then updates would be more efficient.

Comment: Ok - I'll remove the language portion - the second half is stil viable.  I'll make a small change to use only one content area, but you will still want to split up the languages for performance.

Comment: Let me confirm then, I can upload a file (portfolio or landing page?) and use "ContentAreaByName()" to access the file. The file will include all of the variables for each language set. You seem to also be suggesting perhaps that each language feature a unique ContentAreaByName() file to help streamline loading. So French would be a file of variable settings in French and Spanish would be the same for Spanish. Using the statements will determine which ContentAreaByName() is accessed which then determines the var values for the given language. Am I getting that correct?

Comment: No - you are creating content areas in exacttarget.  Don't load the external files - that will be slower.  Using the static files would not be appropriate.

Comment: I'm still missing "something". So first I create a new landing page, this one with content areas instead of a simple HTML page (not on with that part yet, but I'm listening - currently ALL logic & translations are in the body of 3 separate pages, having this as one file and one line of code in three places simplifies my life a LOT) so you're suggesting 1 landing page w/content areas, and based on the langID setting, the statement would access the various contentAreas by name within that page. Page could be "Translations" and "transFrench, TransGerman etc. content areas- correct?

Comment: Finally getting back to this very critical aspect of simplifying our systems. The directions on ET weren't very helpful. While they show how to create a content area, there isn't anything detailed on how to get that content to be available to a landing page using the ContentAreaByName(). I thought I'd test it by trying to display a copyright like this: 
%%[ SET @copyright = ContentAreaByName(ContentVars-aa)]%%
%%=v(@copyright)=%% but of course that isn't working. Any specifics on how to connect to the content area may help.

Comment: Try just using %%=ContentAreaByName('ContentVars-aa')=%% near the top of the page. Then all code in the content area is called as if it were already there. So if you have `@foo` in the content area, it would be called `@foo` here.

Comment: That worked, I was over complicating it, no var needed, just yank it in and WHOOMP! I'm now pondering a two line method where one sets the language var, and the next sets the translation contentarea based on a pages language. I hope this helps others too, (good luck others!)